# How to find path on express app for middleware

Tags: node.js, express, routes, middleware, express-4

So my router looks like this:

```
const app = express();
app.use('/login', router);

app.listen(3000, () => {
    app._router.stack.forEach((middleware: any) => {
     console.log(middleware);
    })
})
```

when I console .log that middleware I get:

```
Layer {
  handle:
   { [Function: router]
     params: {},
     _params: [],
     caseSensitive: undefined,
     mergeParams: undefined,
     strict: undefined,
     stack: [ [Layer] ] },
  name: 'router',
  params: undefined,
  path: undefined,
  keys: [],
  regexp:
   { /^\/login\/?(?=\/|$)/i fast_star: false, fast_slash: false },
  route: undefined }
```

Only part where I can see route path for the middleware is regexp but it is not easy to extract...

Any idea how can I get path from express app

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the constructor](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/3ed5090ca91f6a387e66370d57ead94d886275e1/lib/router/layer.js#L33-L50), the original path isn't retained anywhere.

Comment: if i do like this: ```app.post('login', ...)``` it will return path: ```route:
   Route { path: 'login', stack: [ [Layer] ], methods: { get: true } } }```.  You can try... But for ```app.use('login, ...)``` path not working. It must be some bug

Comment: @VladimirDjukic yes, but that `Route` instance isn't available in the `Layer` instance (`route: undefined`).

Comment: What exactly is it that you want to do?

Comment: I want to loop trought ```express()``` and get all full paths and methods

Comment: But to what purpose?

Comment: To make easy validation and automatic API documentation npm pkg

Comment: Take a look at this module: https://github.com/ivanoff/express2md It can generate API documentation for an Express instance, so I assume that it has a way of determining the paths from the routes.

Comment: It not using express Router. It creating routes directly on express instance

Answer (score 0):

app.js

```
const app = express();
const { getRoutes } = require('./utils/getRoutes');
getRoutes(app)
```

getRoutes.js

```
let counter = 0;
const getRoutes = (app) => {
    let routes = [];
    app._router.stack.forEach(function(middleware) {
        let regexp = middleware.regexp.toString();
        regexp = regexp.slice(3);
        const index = regexp.indexOf('/?(');
        regexp = regexp.slice(0, index - 1);

        if (middleware.route) {
            routes.push({ child: middleware.route.path, parent: regexp });
        } else if (middleware.name === 'router') {
            middleware.handle.stack.forEach(function(handler) {
                counter++;

                if (counter % 2 === 1) {
                    return;
                }
                route = handler.route;
                route && routes.push({ child: route.path, parent: regexp });
            });
        }
    });

    return routes
};

module.exports.getRoutes = getRoutes;
```

hope you will get all your register path